# How do I add a boolean variable to my model player in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I want to add a playing bool variable to my model player.

This is what I think would work.

```
rails g migration player playing:bool
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you want to add a column to an existing model you could use like this

```
rails generate migration AddPlayingToPlayers playing:boolean
```

this is what it generates

```
class AddPlayingToPlayers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :players, :playing, :boolean
  end
end
```

and in ruby world boolean values are often refer with `?`, as an example if you want to check if the playing is `true` or `false`

```
@player = Player.first
@player.playing? # true or false
```